# How is distance measured in TIGER/Line data for roads?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, data, united-states, tiger

So I'm working with some TIGER data for network analysis, and it comes with no speed or time attributes, so I was able to assign average speeds to the various road types, and I was going to use field calculator to populate the time field using the Speed and Shape_Length fields, but all of the lengths are very small, 0.00xxx. Is there something I need to do to convert them, or are they just measured in some strange unit of distance that I am not aware of?

This is what I have:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TIGER/Line data use Global Coordinate System North American Datum of 1983 (GCS NAD83). Based on [About the 2015 TIGER/Line Shapefiles](http://www2.census.gov/geo/pdfs/maps-data/data/tiger/tgrshp2015/TGRSHP2015_TechDoc_Ch2.pdf), each .prj file contains the following:

> GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]

Which means the length you get is in (Degree). You need to convert the projection to meter to get the correct length.

Comment: Can I use field calculator to do that, or do I need to reproject?

I ended up using Meters = Degrees * (meters per degree), where at the latitude in question, a degree is 111010.50m. Does that seem correct?

Comment: It is better to reproject your data to suitable projection (in meter).